# What is the topology on an infinite product space of finite discrete spaces?

Tags: general-topology

Specifically, what is the set of open sets in $X=\{\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n\in\{0,1\}\}$? Is it also a discrete topology?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not discrete. It is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

Taking $(x_0,x_1,\ldots)$ to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2x_n/3^{n+1}$
is a homeomorphism to the usual middle-third Cantor set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ has the product topology, the open subsets of $X$ are obtained by specifying the value of the sequence $(x_n)_n$ at finitely many indices. In particular, if $x=(x_n)_n$ is a point in $X$ then $\{x\}$ is not an open subset of $X$, so $X$ is not discrete.

However, $X$ is totally disconnected, and is compact by Tychonoff's theorem. Interestingly, $X$ is homeomorphic both to the Cantor set (as mentioned in the other answer) and to the $2$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_2$.